# SQL server populate a table based on another table with a substring as column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to populate a table based on a given table:

Given table t1:

```
 id1 (string), id2 (string), value (float)
 tyb            uanwe_A        6963       
 tyb            uanwe_B        979       
 tyb            uanwe_C        931
```

I need :

```
 id1, id2,   vA,   vB,    vC
 tyb  uanwe  6963   979  931
```

My SQL server query:

```
 select case substring(id2, 6, 1)
        when 'A' then [value]
        end as [vA]
 from t1
```

but, this does not work for me **because I got many "null" in the case that substring(id2, 6, 1) is not 'A'.**

```
 select case substring(id2, 6, 1)
        when 'A' then [value]  end as [vA]
        when 'B' then [value]  end as [vB]
        when 'C' then [value]  end as [vC]
     end 
 from t1
```

I GOT ERROR:

```
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why doesnt work? you get an error or a different result as you expect?

Comment: because I got many "null" in the case that substring(id2, 6, 1) is not 'A'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this will help you

```
 declare @temp table
 (id1 nvarchar(99), id2 nvarchar(99), value int)
 insert into @temp values ('tyb','uanwe_A',6963)       
 insert into @temp values ('tyb','uanwe_B',979 )      
 insert into @temp values ('tyb','uanwe_C',931 )   

select id1, substring(id2,1, 5) id2, 
        max(case substring(id2,7, 1)
        when 'A' then value  end) vA,
        max(case substring(id2,7, 1)
        when 'B' then value   end) vB,
        max(case substring(id2,7, 1)
        when 'C' then value  end) vC
from @temp GROUP BY id1,substring(id2,1, 5)
```

Comment: No, I need value not the column name filled in the new table.

Comment: @user3750163 see updated answer it would be great if you post your Q from next timew with sql fiddle so you can get most accurate and esap

Answer (score 1):

Try [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5c75/1)**

```
-- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT [id1], [uanwe_A], [uanwe_B], [uanwe_C]
FROM
(   SELECT [id1], [id2], [value]
    FROM table1) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG([value])
FOR [id2] IN ([uanwe_A], [uanwe_B], [uanwe_C])
) AS PivotTable;
```

**OUTPUT**

I add another id1 to make the example more clear

```
| id1 | uanwe_A | uanwe_B | uanwe_C |
|-----|---------|---------|---------|
| tyb |    6963 |     979 |     931 |
| tyC |     111 |     222 |     333 |
```

Comment: it does not work for me. If it is 'B', I need to write it to column "vB"

Comment: Then rewrite your question. Because that wasnt what you ask  Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Check now. Im using PIVOT instead

Comment: Can you expand your sample data a litle bit? So i can see what other kind of `id2` will be there or are just those 3?